# How To Remove The "+ Add New Category" Link From A Category Metabox

Tags: metabox, customization, magento

Inside of a Wordpress category metabox or any custom taxonomy box for that matter there is a link with the text "+ Add New Category" is there a way this link can be removed preferably without resorting to JS or CSS hacks to hide it? A way to hide it using some kind of filter or action hook would be best.

If no action hook or filter method exists to remove it, I would be open to JS and CSS solutions as a last resort.

The reason I am doing this is because I have a Wordpress installation integrated with Magento and I am creating and populating a custom taxonomy called "brands" with a list of brands from the Magento database so a post can be assigned to a brand. Obviously this means I don't want users to be able to add in their own terms and only be able to choose the brands added in dynamically to keep it in-sync with Magento.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default metaboxes are registred in the file `wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php`. There you can find the function `post_categories_meta_box()` which will generate the taxonomy metabox. Currently there is no hook available to filter the output. But you can do one of the following:

1. Use `remove_meta_box()` to remove the existing category metabox and register your own with `add_meta_box()`. Copy&Past the existing code to your new metabox function and remove the code block from line `345` to `367`.
2. The cleaner way: Remove the `edit_terms` capability from your user roles with `remove_cap()`. If you look in the metabox function, on line `345` you can see an if-statement which checks if the user has the capability `edit_terms`. If so, the `+ Add New XY` will be displayed. Problem here, the name of the capability is dynamic and could be anything. If someone registers a taxonomy with a different capability naming, this will probably not work (untested).

Comment: Ah, yes. Capabilities is a nice way actually. However I don't want to remove the ability from other taxonomies just one in particular. I decided hiding the link with some good old fashioned CSS was the easiest choice. Thanks for the great suggestions.

Comment: I can't comment on rofflox's post, but the capability looks to have been changed to "manage_categories"

Comment: Thank you! This is the best method I could find, I am using this on a multisite so using the capability "setup_network" to limit site admins from using these capabilities for a taxonomy added by a plugin which needs to remain unedited.